# Why my script follows /etc/hosts but the browsers do not, when there is a SOCKS proxy?

Tags: dns, proxy, osx-mountain-lion, hosts, socks

My MacBook in office does not have internet access. So I set up an instant SOCKS Proxy over SSH to access stackoverflow. I mainly use my MacBook for development so I rely on `/etc/hosts` and virtual hosts to test some sites locally.

However, when I try to add an entry to `/etc/hosts`, the browser does not go to the site I expected ...

My MacBook's WIFI is off and is connected to the company LAN:

```
 IP address:  192.168.8.250
 Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
 Router:      192.168.8.1
 DNS server:  8.8.8.8
```

Be default, there is not internet access.

There a Linux development box (192.168.12.128) which has access to the internet, so I set up an instant SOCKS proxy to gain internet access for my MacBook:

```
 ssh -fND localhost:30000 ohho@192.168.12.128
```

Then in my MacBook's System Preferences > Network > Proxies

```
 (Enable) SOCKS Proxy
 SOCKS Proxy sever: 127.0.0.1:30000
 Bypass proxy settings for these Hosts & Domains:
   *.local, 169.254/16, 127.0.0.1
```

Now I can surf the web, so far so good.

For development, I set up a few entries in `/etc/hosts` for virtual hosts purpose:

```
 127.0.0.1 air.company.com
```

In `bash`:

```
 $ ping air.company.com
 PING air.ohho.es (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
 64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.046 ms

 $ curl air.company.com
 <html>OK</html>
```

It looks good and `curl` returns the content of the `index.html` nicely.

However, if I try to open the site:`http://air.company.com` in the browsers (Safari/Chrome/Firefox), none of them returns the result like `curl` did. Chrome give an error:

> This webpage is not available The webpage at http://air.company.com/
>   might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new
>   web address. Error 120 (net::ERR_SOCKS_CONNECTION_FAILED): Unknown
>   error.

If I add another entry in `/etc/hosts`:

```
 127.0.0.1 www.microsoft.com
```

In `bash`, it looks OK:

```
 $ ping www.microsoft.com
 PING www.microsoft.com (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
 64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.047 ms
 64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.128 ms
 ^C
 --- www.microsoft.com ping statistics ---
 2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
 round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.047/0.087/0.128/0.041 ms

 $ curl www.microsoft.com
 <html>OK</html>
```

I also try using ruby script:

```
 require 'socket'
 require 'curl'

 ip = IPSocket.getaddress('www.microsoft.com')
 puts ip

 puts

 http = Curl.get("http://www.microsoft.com/")
 puts http.body_str
```

The output looks OK:

```
 $ bundle exec ruby openweb.rb 
 127.0.0.1

 <html>OK</html>
```

However, when I use the browsers, the browsers return the content from the web server of the *real* Microsoft site, instead of the content from my MacBook (127.0.01). Why?

p.s.:

If I disable the SOCKS proxy, the browser returns the content from 127.0.0.1 correctly.

If I disconnect the LAN cable, the browser returns the content from 127.0.0.1 correctly.

Answer (score 3):

SOCKS5 will do DNS look-ups remotely; this is a good thing for security.

I think what you want is to instruct your browser not to use the proxy for internal or your custom development addresses.

To do that, set your "Bypass proxy settings for these Hosts & Domains:" to include `*.company.com`. If you have particularly complex settings, you can set up a [proxy access control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config) (aka `.pac`) file that allows very granular control of what goes over the proxy and what is accessed directly.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to answer it at my best, as I already had this problem.

When you are using a Socks5 connection, your ip resolution is forwarded to the socks server.

At the version 5 the SOCKS implementation may receive full domain names as the destination and source addresses[[1]](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1928.txt) (page 4).

On the Mac OS the default is SOCKS 5 as indicated in [[2]](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSStream_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSStreamSOCKSProxyConfigurationKey) at (NSStreamSOCKSProxyVersionKey).

So by default the mac client will use SOCKS5 and WILL forward the DNS requests.

I  hope this answer your question:
"Why my script follows /etc/hosts but the browsers do not, when there is a SOCKS proxy?"
--> because the SOCKS5 implementation forward dns requests :)

With Regards

[1](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1928.txt) - http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1928.txt

[2](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSStream_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSStreamSOCKSProxyConfigurationKey) - https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSStream_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSStreamSOCKSProxyConfigurationKey

Answer (score 1):

With SOCKSv4a and SOCKSv5 clients are actually able to have the server connect to a domain *name*, not only to an address (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS#SOCKS4a).

```
                                                      ----------
                                                      -   DNS  -
                                                      ┐---------
                                                     .
                                                    .
----------------                   ----------------.-
-              ====================-                -
- Browser      = CON microsoft.com - SOCKS Server   -
-              ====================-                -
----------------                   ------------------
```

And since the SOCKS server *has* internet access, you can see the site of Microsoft, and not your local version.

---

Ideas:

- If you are able to change the version of the SOCKS protocol to version 4, it should work.
- Probably better in the long run: Disable remote DNS in the browser, at least Firefox supports this setting: [Network.proxy.socks.remote_dns](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.proxy.socks_remote_dns).

Answer (score 1):

It's a DNS problem. Try resolving the names locally.

Answer (score 0):

I also encounter this problem and solved by just changing `/etc/host` entry

**Just remove:**

> 127.0.0.1 www.microsoft.com

**and add:**

> 192.168.8.250 www.microsoft.com

inshort add your server `ip` address instead of `loopback` `ip`